# How to create listview onItemclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I want to create listview. I got the value from the JSON. Here I got the value from the json    into listview but i can't get the onItemclickListener method.   Why this is happening I don't know ,Please help me my coding as shown below.

Logcat is not displaying anything.

Thanks.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contests_listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:focusable="true">
</ListView>
```

Activity.java

```
public class Activites_Activity extends CheerfoolznativeActivity {

private ListView contests_listView;
private ProgressBar pgb;
ActivitiesBean bean;
ArrayList<Object> listActivities;
ListAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
    setHeader("Activites");


    contests_listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contests_listView);
    pgb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.contests_progressBar);
    listActivities = new ArrayList<Object>();

    new FetchActivitesTask().execute();

}

public class FetchActivitesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int i =0;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
         pgb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = "my json URL";
        String strResponse = util.makeWebCall(url);

        try {

            //my json logic here        
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pgb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        displayAdapter();
    }
}

public void displayAdapter()
{
    adapter = new ListAdapter(this, listActivities);
    contests_listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    contests_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Title => "+items.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            System.out.println("=========== Click");
            bean = (ActivitiesBean) adapter.getItem(position);

            Intent in1 = new Intent(Activites_Activity.this, Activity_display.class);
            in1.putExtra("ActivityObject", bean);
            startActivity(in1);
        }
    });


}
}
```

I also use this

```
contests_listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Comment: does it show items in the ListView? and does it print `=========== Click` in logs when you click an item?

Comment: did you try setOnItemSelectedListener ?  I think it might default call that listener?

Comment: @Waqas ,yes I got the value in listview but don't show click in logs,also don't show toast.

Comment: @MikeIsrael ,Thanks. yes I tried that but that display the toast when I focus the listview not click the listview.

Comment: i was talking about **System.out.println**, not toast

Comment: There is no action take place clicking on the item, neither System.out.println nor Toast.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this :

```
contests_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) contests_listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(this,"You selected : " + item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it not working,please let me know if there is other solution for this problem.

Comment: But what error are you getting? If logcat doesn't give any output then try resetting the ADB through DDMS.

Comment: I get `contests_listView` must be declared as final?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

Toast.makeText(this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Finally I get the solution, By mistake I take the ScrollView into my listitem,After remove it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
 contests_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapaterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent in1 = new Intent(Activites_Activity.this, Activity_display.class);

            startActivity(in1);
        }
    });
```